# Unable to install MySQL on Windows 10 - Installer hangs indefinitely

Tags: mysql, windows

I am trying to install MySQL on a Windows 10 PC. I downloaded the installer package and followed those steps

1. Went to https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/windows/
2. clicked on "MySQL Installer"
3. Scrolled to Generally Available(GA) Releases section
4. Clicked on "**Windows (x86, 32-bit), MSI Installer**" (mysql-installer-community-5.7.21.0.msi) and it started the download.
5. Once the download was complete, I double clicked on the installer and it gave a usual pop-up for any installation like,"Do you want this app to make changes to your device?" after clicking on "yes" for the answer to this question, it shows "**Please wait while Windows configures MySQL-Installer-community**" like below screenshot.

[image]

And then it keeps showing this installation progress bar for a very long time. Like more than 7-8 hours and the installation never completes

So it seems something is wrong as I don't think MySQL installation needs this long time. I tried to restart my computer and then delete any files related to MySQL from my computer and then started the whole process of installation again. But no luck yet

Anyone has any suggestion on this or did anyone face this kind of issue before? If so, is there a fix or a work around for this?

Answer (score 44, accepted):

ok. So finally this is how I resolved my issue. And I found the solution at   https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=82004 . The solution to this problem is to **close an open "Windows installer" (the one using 0 memory and CPU) via task manager** and the installation should begin running as expected.

Comment: Since you clearly put some work into this and found this solution yourself, and your answer is the correct one, you should be able to un-accept the answer that you accepted, and then accept your own answer as correct.  Obviously that would not be the courteous thing to do if you got a solid answer from someone else, but that doesn't appear to be the case, here.

Comment: That's true. I wanted to accept my own answer. But seems we can accept our own answer only after two days. That's the message I get when I try to accept my own answer. This issue was irritating, tricky  and took time to find out what's wrong with the installation. Thanks to the person who found the resolution of this error @ https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=82004

Comment: Same issue here. I killed the 32-bit Windows Installer and I was able to proceed with the download. Thanks for the help :)

Comment: Hahaha its silly but worked after closing windows installer with 0 memory and cpu.

Comment: Bug still exists. I'm on version 8.0.26

Answer (score 18):

Alternative solution: Use an administrator command prompt to run the MySQL installer on Windows 10. Details:

(Note: if you have any problems in the following steps, you can try to restart your computer. Then restart the steps.)

1. Right-click the Start/Windows icon in the bottom-left corner of Windows.
2. Click: Windows PowerShell (Admin).
3. A window asks: Do you want to allow this app to make changes to your device? Click: Yes.
4. Change to the directory with the MySQL installer. For example, if you downloaded the MySQL installer, type something like:

`cd C:\Users\my_username\Downloads\`

(Note: To save some typing, you can type a few characters, and then press the tab key, to make Windows show you various auto-completion options.)

5. Run the MySQL installer. Type something like the following command---make sure to include the period and backslash at the beginning---and press Enter.

`.\mysql-installer-community-8.0.11.0.msi`

Note: The idea of using an administrator command prompt came from John Geffe, in the link below, which was cited in the answer written by the original poster (user8425592):

> https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=82004
>
> Bug #82004    MySQL Installer freezes during "Please wait while Windows configures..." phase
>
> [6 Feb 3:58] John Geffe
>
> To get past this problem I had to run the .msi installer from an the
>   Administrator command prompt. Hopefully this helps someone in the
>   future.
>
> [19 Apr 18:14] Jim McCauley
>
> John Geffe: Thanks! Your note on installing as an administrator seems
>   to have taken care of the problem.

Comment: this resolve my problem, end task manager and restart your computer and then run use command line .\mysql-installer-community-8.0.11.0.msi or your version mysql  .\mysql

Answer (score 9):

this did the trick for me: https://andrewodendaal.com/mysql-community-server-msi-installer-hangs-on-windows-10/

1. run cmd (commandline) as Administrator
2. cd to your location that you downloaded the .MSI to
3. run the “msiexec” commandline tool with option “/i” as follows:
4. msiexec /i [replace with file name]
5. example: msiexec /i mysql-installer-community-5.7.20.0.msi

Comment: OMG it worked!  **None of the other solutions here worked for me**, in case anyone else is having this problem.

Answer (score 3):

Another thing that worked for me was **running the installer in compatibility mode** for previous version of Windows. You can try that as well.

[image]

Comment: after trying one more hours your answer helped me

Answer (score 1):

Go to the link you provided (the first one) and try installing MySql Workbench. That is the version that is commonly used, and one that I verified works in Windows 10. Here is the link: https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/workbench/

Obviously, make sure you choose the right architecture, have the correct permissions to install software, and have enough space on your hard drive, or on the machine you are installing to.

Comment: Workbench != mysql server

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion Yuriy, I downloaded the version from the link you shared. To be very specific, I clicked the link https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/workbench/ then clicked on "Go to Download page" and downloaded "Windows (x86, 32-bit), MSI Installer"  (mysql-installer-community-5.7.21.0.msi).  Once it was downloaded, followed step 5 mentioned above with the new installer that I downloaded. But its paused right where you can see in the picture I shared. Before installing anything from the link you shared, I restarted my computer.

Comment: Also my computer has enough space so I am not expecting any space issues for installation. And its my personal computer so I do have all the installation rights. Regarding architecture, I am not sure what architecture is expected for this installation. Any other suggestions?Regarding architecture, I am not sure what architecture is expected for this installation. Any other suggestions?

Comment: Here is a handy article to check out: https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/workbench/ Check the section that says MySQL Workbench Windows Prerequisites, as well as https://dev.mysql.com/doc/workbench/en/wb-installing-windows.html

Comment: ok so that says, I should have "Microsoft .NET Framework 4.5" and "Microsoft Visual C++ 2015 Redistributable Package" installed first in order to get "Windows (x86, 32-bit), MSI Installer" (mysql-installer-community-5.7.21.0.msi) installed. I'll try it that way and confirm if that worked. Thanks a lot for your quick response and help.

Comment: So I have both "Microsoft .NET Framework 4.5" and "Microsoft Visual C++ 2015 Redistributable Package" installed. However, when I try to install  "Windows (x86, 32-bit), MSI Installer" (mysql-installer-community-5.7.21.0.msi) , the installation begins and then pauses forever with the screen I shared in the picture earlier :( Not sure why the installation halts there. But appreciate your quick response and help with this.

Answer (score 1):

Please install "Update for Visual C++ 2013 and Visual C++ Redistributable Package" from Microsoft Site "http://download.microsoft.com/download/0/5/6/056DCDA9-D667-4E27-8001-8A0C6971D6B1/vcredist_x64.exe"

Please look here at https://support.microsoft.com/en-in/help/3179560/update-for-visual-c-2013-and-visual-c-redistributable-package

Answer (score 1):

Yes, I also got the same problem on my Windows 10.
Followed the Powershell solution and it worked.
Just repeat the above:

1. Click `Start` on bottom left corner
2. Scroll down the application list until Windows Powershell
3. Select `Windows Powershell` again on sub-menu
4. Type in `cd` (to change to your .msi folder)
5. Type `.\xxxxx.msi` (this is the installer file name)

All good.

Comment: Can you describe or link to the "Powershell solution"?

Comment: Hi, you just click the bottom left corner "Windows" icon. 
It pops up programs list and you do the same as when you open other program like it is in alphabetical order.
Scroll down until you see the category by "W", then you will see the Windows Powershell.
Click it to pop up a command window.
Change the directory to where you saved the installer
eg. cd c:\temp\mysqldownload
Then type:
.\[name of the msi]

Answer (score 0):

Once you install the above package run the installer again and do the steps. You will be able to install the mysql-installer-community-5.7.21.0 for 64 bit windows 10

Answer (score 0):

closing Windows Installer instances using 0 memory and CPU helps me to get past this problem.

Answer (score 0):

For me on **Window-10** machine, there was a problem with the "**mysql-connector-net-8.0.11.msi**". I was **not able to** **uninstall** this and hence all my subsequent efforts to install MySQL were failing. I did the following to overcome this issue.

1. Re-installed "**mysql-connector-net-8.0.11.msi**" [Get it here](https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/file/?id=476984) and used the '**Repair**' option
2. Installed the "**mysql-installer-web-community-8.0.11.0.msi**"

These two things solved my problem. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

The reson is your antivirus didn't allow the mysql, so  Disable protection(until restart),( in your task bar right side click the arrow and right click to antivirus,to select (Disable protection(until restart)).then restart your computer again install mysql installer it will work.

Answer (score 0):

For this issue just run .msi file in command administration like

```
E:\mysql-installer-community-8.0.20.0.msi\
```

follow this link:

https://kb.foxitsoftware.com/hc/en-us/articles/360040660611-How-to-install-MSI-from-command-line-with-administrator

Answer (score 0):

In my case, an upgrade to 5.7.29 on Windows 10 via *mysql-installer-web-community-8.0.20.0.msi*, the install froze "backing up the database".  The log tab showed no activity for 8 minutes.  I clicked on cancel, then at the "are you sure" prompt I declined to cancel, and all of a sudden the install was working again.   Very strange...

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same problem, preparing but can never get started. Tried to close other installation programs with no use, but I took the inspiration and proceeded with restart the computer and it worked nicely. So, I think the issue is to get rid of everything that could be in the background running that somehow interferes the installation.

Answer (score 0):

You should run the installer as an administrator but this specific installation may not provide an option for this. Some might have it but it's most likely that it's unavailable for many users. So you should run it in cmd or powershell. And don't forget to run these shells as an administrator coz that's the whole point here. Once there, navigate to the installer's location which usually is in the downloads directory and run it using this command  ./name.msi
Make sure no other ongoing installation of this instance. Close it if there exists one and undo the changes made by uninstalling it from the panel. If still facing difficulties, try restarting your machine and repeat this procedure...

Have fun

Answer (score 0):

I had the same Problem, A simple solution is to give access the "SYSTEM" to the msiserver...I know, this is hard to understand what I am saying....You can Simply see this Video and you will definitely find the answer https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6SdXMjXmnUk, It is a matter of just 3 minutes...

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same issue of taking too much time to install mysql community installer.I tried 3 times by cancelling the installation and restarting to perform a new installation.But had same issue. I tried 2 things

- First to end all tasks associated with installation which I performed for installing mysql using **Task Manager**

Reinitiated the installation but didn't solved my issue.

- Secondly tried to install through **Windows Powershell as admin**, which solved the problem.

1. Click on the Windows icon/start on the bottom left corner.
2. Right click and select the option **Windows Powershell (Admin)**.
3. A pop up window will ask Do you want to allow this app to make changes to your device?....Click **Yes**.
4. Now cd to your downloads folder/wherever you downloaded the .msi file (For example cd C:\Users\MYPC\Downloads).
5. Once you reach to the folder where the .msi file is kept, run the following command.
   **.\mysql-installer-web-community-8.0.23.0.msi** (Note: this is the version which I have downloaded, modify as your version).